# There is no visual display during server run

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
      </div>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="hello.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

the script file hello.js:

```
const container =  document.getElementById('container');
const div = <div><h1><u>hello, from react + jsx</u></h1></div>
ReactDOM.render(div, container);
```

The page shows nothing, and the console shows an error:

```
**Uncaught ReferenceError: h1 is not defined
at <anonymous>:18:17
at run (babel.js:61531)
at check (babel.js:61597)
at result.<computed>._extends.content (babel.js:61624)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (babel.js:61549)**
```

and another error:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

What's wrong?

Comment: do you have babel configured for jsx?

Comment: sure.                                                                                                                                  So weird, I added ;                                                                                                        const div = <div><h1><u>hello, from react + jsx</u></h1></div>; now it's working!

Comment: on initial loading everything is displayed without any error                                                            But when refreshed, the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) is displayed

Comment: you can have a look in your browsers dev tools to see which request has failed. 404 means that a request URL could not be found